# Transit visa to UAE for Costa Rican citizen

Tags: visas, transit, transit-visas, uae, costa-rican-citizens

I am a Costa Rican citizen living in Costa Rica.

I am looking at visiting Kenya, and my best option seems to fly to Dubai on a larger airline, then get a smaller airline from Dubai to Kenya.

Let's say I arrive at Dubai December 1st, and my return ticket is December 31st. I also have tickets from Dubai to Kenya for December 2nd and back to Dubai on December 28th.

From what I understand, there's a 96-hour transit visa that lets you stay 4 days or less. Is this true? What are the requirements, where and how is it requested, how much does it cost and can a Costa Rican citizen get it?

Would this allow me to arrive back in Dubai a few days before my outbound flight and visit Dubai?

**Edit**: A lot of information online and other StackExchange questions are about US or EU citizens. I haven't found information specifically about Costa Rican citizens.

Comment: According to the Embassy of the United Arab Emirates in Washington D.C., under Visas for Non-US Citizens, it states: _The Embassy does not issue Transit Visa, You should contact the airline company that will fly you to the UAE and enquire from them about the possibility of traveling to the UAE without prior visa._

Comment: Hi @CGCampbell! I visited that website and it's information is for Non-US Citizens that have a permanent residence in the USA. So it doesn't apply in my case.